# tikz in row reduction and gather columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

I would like to make a diagram using tikz that looks like this
[image]

I would like it to have two rows. The first row is matrix row reduction, and the second row is to gather some columns of row reduction matrices in the first row and has arrows connecting (eg first column in the first matrix in the first row connects to the first column of L in the second row (I assume this needs tikz). I wonder if this is achievable in latex. If not probably I would just scan this equation.

A sample code is listed below:

```
  \[
      \begin{pmatrix}
          2 & 4 & -1 & 5 & -2 \\
          -4 & -5 & 3 & 8 & 1 \\
          2 & -5 & -4 & 1 & 8 \\
          -6 & 0 & 7 & -3 & 1
      \end{pmatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pmatrix}
          2 & 4 &   &  \\
           & 3 &  &  \\
           & -9 &  &  \\
           & 12 &  &
      \end{pmatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pmatrix}
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & 2 & 1 \\
           &  &  & 4 & 7
      \end{pmatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pmatrix}
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & 2 & 1 \\
           &  &  &  & 5
      \end{pmatrix}
      = U
  \]
  %%%% how to add arrows between the two rows?
  \[
  L = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
      3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I like to see the code for math expression you show it in very unreadably way in your question ... Help us to help you!

Comment: Hi @Zarko, sorry I didn't make it clear, but it's intended to be a general problem so any number is sufficient. I added a sample data in the description.

Comment: In general, if you like to have your math  expression in two (or more) lines, just use one of the `amsmath` package math environments, which enable this. F for example `multline`, `split` etc.

Comment: Cool @Zarko thanks. I guess I made a vague description. I'd like to have arrows connecting the matrices. For example the second column of L in the second row has an arrow connecting to the second column of the second matrix in the first row

Comment: Than please edit your question again clearly show us, what you after. What can be so far understood from your question, see my answer ...

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, I've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, but where arrows has start and end? bottom of column -- top of column? Make an sketch, for example based on my answer. For arrows seems to be use of `tikzmar` on pof promising solution or write your equations as image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `nicematrix` and `tikzmark`. Note that you must compile 3 times.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
  \[
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[left-margin=.5em]
          \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{4-1}{}2 & 4 & -1 & 5 & -2 \\
          -4 & -5 & 3 & 8 & 1 \\
          2 & -5 & -4 & 1 & 8 \\
          \tikzmarknode{a1}{-6} & 0 & 7 & -3 & 1
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}
          2 & 4 &   &  \\
           & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{3-1}{}3 &  &  \\
           & -9 &  &  \\
           & \tikzmarknode{a2}{12} &  &
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{2-1}{}2 & 1 \\
           &  &  & \tikzmarknode{a3}{4} & 7
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin=.5em]
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & 2 & 1 \\
           &  &  &  & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed,red}]{1-1}{}\tikzmarknode{a4}{5}
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      = U
  \]
\vspace{1cm}
  \[
    L = \begin{pNiceMatrix}
      \tikzmarknode{b1}{1} & \tikzmarknode{b2}{0} & \tikzmarknode{b3}{0} & \tikzmarknode{b4}{0} \\
      -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
      3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
  \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](a1) to[out=south, in=north] (b1);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](a2) to[out=south, in=north] (b2);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](a3.west) to[out=west, in=north] (b3);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](a4) to[out=south, in=north] (b4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is only a slight variation of the (very good) solution of Sandy G. It shows how it is possible to obtain the same output by using the nodes created by `nicematrix` (without `tikzmark`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
  \[
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[left-margin=.5em,name=A1]
          \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{4-1}{}2 & 4 & -1 & 5 & -2 \\
          -4 & -5 & 3  & 8  & 1 \\
          2  & -5 & -4 & 1  & 8 \\
          -6 & 0  & 7  & -3 & 1
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=A2]
          2 & 4 &   &  \\
           & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{3-1}{}3 &  &  \\
           & -9 &  &  \\
           & 12 &  &
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=A3]
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed, red}]{2-1}{} 2 & 1 \\
           &  &  & 4 & 7
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      \sim
      \begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin=.5em,name=A4]
          2 & 4 &  -1 & 5 & 2  \\
            & 3 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
            & &  & 2 & 1 \\
           &  &  &  & \Block[tikz={draw, thick, dashed,red}]{1-1}{} 5
      \end{pNiceMatrix}
      = U
  \]
\vspace{1cm}
  \[
    L = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=B]
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
      3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
  \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](A1-4-1) to[out=south, in=north] (B-1-1);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](A2-4-2) to[out=south, in=north] (B-1-2);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](A3-4-4.west) to[out=west, in=north] (B-1-3);
  \draw[red, ->, shorten <=1.5mm, shorten >=1mm](A4-4-5) to[out=south, in=north] (B-1-4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{gather*}
 \begin{multlined}
\begin{pmatrix}
   2 &  4 & -1 &  5 & -2 \\
  -4 & -5 &  3 &  8 &  1 \\
   2 & -5 & -4 &  1 &  8 \\
  -6 &  0 &  7 & -3 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 &  4 &  \\
    &  3 &  \\
    & -9 &  \\
    & 12 & 
\end{pmatrix}       \\  % <---
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2   & 4 & -1 & 5 &  2   \\
    & 3 &  1 & 2 & -3   \\
    &   &    & 2 &  1   \\
    &   &    & 4 &  7
\end{pmatrix}
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2   & 4 & -1 & 5 &  2   \\
    & 3 &  1 & 2 & -3   \\
    &   &    & 2 &  1   \\
    &   &    &   &  5
\end{pmatrix} = U
\end{multlined}     \\  % <---
%
L = \begin{pmatrix}
       1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
      -2 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
       3 &  4 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

For more information about writing math in LaTeX see [wiki, basic math](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), especial [wiki, advance math](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics) and other introductory texts.

**Edit:**

- You (so far) not provide information where should start and end your desired arrow.
- So, below is just wild guessing what you after
- If my guessing is wrong, at least is given a principle how can you draw arrows between equation elements using `tikzmark` library of `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                tikzmark}   % <---
\tikzset{FIT/.style = {fit=#1, node contents={},
                       draw=red, rounded corners, thick, 
                       inner sep=1pt}              
        }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{gather*}
 \begin{multlined}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tikzmarknode{a}{2}
    &  4 & -1 &  5 & -2 \\
-4  & -5 &  3 &  8 &  1 \\
 2  & -5 & -4 &  1 &  8 \\
\tikzmarknode{b}{-6}  
    &  0 &  7 & -3 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 &  4 &  \\
    &  3 &  \\
    & -9 &  \\
    & 12 & 
\end{pmatrix}       \\  % <---
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2   & 4 & -1 & 5 &  2   \\
    & 3 &  1 & 2 & -3   \\
    &   &    & 2 &  1   \\
    &   &    & 4 &  7
\end{pmatrix}
      \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2   & 4 & -1 & 5 &  2   \\
    & 3 &  1 & 2 & -3   \\
    &   &    & 2 &  1   \\
    &   &    &   &  5
\end{pmatrix} = U
\end{multlined}     \\  % <---
%
L = \begin{pmatrix}
       \tikzmarknode{c}{1}    
      ~  &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
       \tikzmarknode{d}{-2}
         &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
       \tikzmarknode{e}{3}
         &  4 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (A)   [FIT=(a) (b)];
\node (B)   [FIT=(c) (d) (e)];
    \draw[red!50,ultra thick, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]